# FreeNAS SubVersion/GIT Repo

Tags: git, svn, freenas

I'm running FreeNAS 9.1. A Friend of mine was asking me the other day:

Can you run  Subversion or Git repo using FreeNAS? Is there a plugin or an easy way to make this happen?

Thanks for the Help! BTW Upgrading from 8.3 -> 9.1 was SUPER easy. good work freeNas team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [subversion](http://www.freshports.org/devel/subversion/) and [git](http://www.freshports.org/devel/git/) are available as FreeBSD ports.

See the [relevant documentation](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Installing_non-PBI_Software) on how to install those on FreeNAS.

If you are new to ports, try installing packages first; it's easier.
However, it you want to compile one of them with non-default options (see "Configuration Options" on the pages linked to above), you'll have to install the ports tree and install them from source.